# Two monitors of same model. What is causing one of them to be dimmer than the other?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings, color-profiles

I have two ASUS VS239H-P monitors. One of them had a blue tint on the right half of the screen recently, so I sent it in for RMA, and it appears that they gave me either a new or refurbished model because it came back in original ASUS packaging with all other accessories. Anyhow, I connect the second monitor to the computer, and I notice that it is dimmer.

Of course, I try resetting both monitors to their factory settings, making  sure that the Nvidia control panel has the same color settings for both displays. However, the other one is definitely dimmer.

I also looked into Windows Color Management, but neither monitor is using a Windows display calibration.

Both monitors are connected via HDMI, though one cable is HDMI to DisplayPort since my 980 ti only has 1 HDMI port. I tried switching the cables, but the problem still remains.

Is this a hardware issue that I should raise to ASUS again?

Comment: Can you not just adjust the brightness of one to match the other? It wouldn't surprise me that monitors are different out of the box, the only problem would be if one wouldn't go high/low enough to match the other.

Comment: It is perfectly normal for consumer-grade monitors to show quite a bit of variation in color balance and brightness even among those of identical make and model.  The expectation is that if you care enough you will either calibrate the monitors yourself or buy more expensive high-end monitors that are factory pre-calibrated and give you at least some assurance of consistent performance (within some margin of course).

Comment: I did not know that the deviations from the manufacturing process could vary so much. Thank you for the insight.